Numerically computing time delay between two functions
Wikipedia claims that the argmax of the cross correlation can be thought of as the time-delay between two functions.
Using scipy.signal.correlate and randomly shifted Gaussians uniformly sampled, I have been able to compute the delay between two signals.
However, if I don't use a function of rapid decay, then the results are extremely poor. For example, if $f_1(t) := A\tanh(kt)$ and $f_2(t) := A\tanh(k(t-\tau))$, I cannot recover $\tau$ with any regularity.
What is the correct way to compute the delay between two functions if they are not functions of rapid decay? Should they be extended to a large domain and "mollified" in some way, or are other techniques required?
Code for reference:
import numpy as np
import scipy
tmax = 4.0
times = np.linspace(-tmax, tmax, 2048)
k = 4
v1 = np.tanh(k*times)
expected_shift = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)
v2 = np.tanh(k*(times-expected_shift))
cross_correlation = scipy.signal.correlate(v1, v2, mode="same")
idx = np.argmax(cross_correlation)
computed_shift = -tmax + idx * (2*tmax/2048)
print(f"Expected shift: {expected_shift}")
print(f"Computed shift: {computed_shift}")

